# ssh "awk -F" '{print $2}' "

Tags: bash, awk, ssh

```
for VM in $VM_LIST;do
    ssh 10.0.0.163 "mkdir $ROOT$VM`date +%F`"
    ssh 10.0.0.163 'find -name "$VM.vmx" | xargs grep -r vmdk >/vmkd.list | cat /vmkd.list | awk -F\" '{print $2}' | while read list; do find -name "$list" ;done'
done
```

I have a problem with this expression - `awk -F\" '{print $2}'`, it broke my code

```
awk: cmd. line:1: Unexpected end of string
```

What can I do with that???

Comment: use: `'\''` : quote + backslash + quote + quote  for replacing each single quote.

Comment: You send SSH a string enclosed in single quotes containing the command(s) you which to run after the successful connection to your remote machine. Inside your string of commands you have single quotes, effectively ending your string prematurely. You have to "escape" those so that they are considered part of the string using the method that F. Hauri explains in the previous comment.

Comment: *"I have a problem with this expression ... it broke my code"* - How? What is problem or error? Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 1):

You could use here doc

```
for VM in $VM_LIST;do
    ssh 10.0.0.163 /bin/sh <<"eocmd"
mkdir $ROOT$VM`date +%F`
find -name "$VM.vmx" |
    xargs grep -r vmdk >/vmkd.list |
    cat /vmkd.list |
    awk -F\" '{print $2}' |
    while read list; do
        find -name "$list"
    done
eocmd
done
```

Comment: `<<<` should be `<<`?

Comment: @whjm no. `<<<` mean inline doc and `< <(cmd)` (care, there is a space between two `<`!) mean inline command. See `man bash`!!

Comment: hi F. Hauri, i'm really confused. `cmd <<< string` (it's called *here string* in bash) basically means the same as `echo string | cmd`.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. `<<` here document, `<<<""` here string and `< <()` here command. I'v used 1 `<` too much!

Comment: could you also replace *inline doc* with *here document*?